# Django Rest Framework not login after registration

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have a site on the Django and I have custom User model. On site, where I use Django Forms, I can register  and after login, and it works well. Then I started to use a DRF and Django-rest-auth. I write a custom register serializer, after I wrote a path for it in the settings.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ideas.models import Post, Unit, StatusOfPost
from accounts.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from allauth.account import app_settings as allauth_settings
from allauth.utils import email_address_exists
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from allauth.account.utils import setup_user_email

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    email = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    password1 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'first_name': self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
            'last_name': self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),
            'address': self.validated_data.get('address', ''),
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'password': self.validated_data.get('password', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'phone_number': self.validated_data.get('phone_number',''),
        }

    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email and email_address_exists(email):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    ("A user is already registered with this e-mail address."))
        return email

    def validate_username(self, username):
        username = get_adapter().clean_username(username)
        return username

    def validate_password1(self, password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password1'] != data['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
            ("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return data

    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])
        user.phone_number = self.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
        user.save()
        return user
```

and it works too and creates a new user and it returns me a token. There is a new user in my admin. But if I want to login in the my site like this new user, site writes me that username or password not valid. And i don't understand why, that in my admin i see this user and i know that write a valid password (i tryied to create different users, but result is one)

I noticed that in the my admin the password of the new user is not encoded as when registering on the site.

for comparison:

**encoded password after registration by API**

```
!Z2Aw4VpN34JidaSNmODVi5MJKRJHTgx0gfROnylA
```

**encoded password after registration on the site:**

```
pbkdf2_sha256$100000$aILnGtv6ClxI$KVg1lwjSKf0REZI/M85i2tN/mTUTLxngNVwo4YaCe08=
```

May be this is a problem, if so, than how is it fix? I don't know.

Thanks to everyone

Comment: You can encode password correctly with make_password method. You import it with `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password` and than encode the password with `password=make_password(not_encoded_password)` However I cannot confirm that this will solve the issue but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function **get_cleaned_data** delete

```
'password': self.validated_data.get('password', ''),
```

and insert

```
'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
'password2': self.validated_data.get('password2', ''),
```

It solved my problem